# Overplotting text in rpart.plot tree

Tags: r, plot, tree

I was trying to plot a tree but the text is overlapping and even though Itried different cex they still are. If I make it smaller then you can`t even read what it`s about. 
Another thing is that it shows me an warning. I thik it may be bacause it fails to convert the variables into factors and I do not know why.
Can anyone help please?
This is my code:

```
cols <- c("Education", "EnvironmentSatisfaction", "JobInvolvement", "JobLevel",
     "JobSatisfaction", "PerformanceRating", "RelationshipSatisfaction", 
     "StockOptionLevel", "TrainingTimesLastYear", "WorkLifeBalance")
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], factor)



 shuffle_index <- sample(1:nrow(df1))

df2 <- df
```

`create_train_test <- function(df2, size = 0.8, train = TRUE) {`

```
 n_row = nrow(df2)


total_row = size * n_row


train_sample <- 1: total_row



if (train == TRUE) {
return (df2[train_sample, ])



 } else {
return (df2[-train_sample, ])}}
```

````
data_train <- create_train_test(df2, 0.8, train = TRUE)
data_test <- create_train_test(df2, 0.8, train = FALSE)
dim(data_train)
dim(data_test)```


`#use the function prop.table() combined with table() to verify if the randomization process is correct.
prop.table(table(data_train$Attrition))
prop.table(table(data_test$Attrition))`

`fit <- rpart(Attrition~., data = data_train, method = 'class')
rpart.plot(fit, extra = 106, cex = 0.45)`
````

Comment: could you also provide output of dput(head(df,50)) ?

Comment: `head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 35
    Age Attrition BusinessTravel DailyRate Department DistanceFromHome
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>              <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1    41 Yes       Travel_Rarely       1102 Sales                   1
2    49 No        Travel_Freque~       279 Research ~        8
3    37 Yes       Travel_Rarely       1373 Research ~         2
4    33 No        Travel_Freque~      1392 Research ~       3
5    27 No        Travel_Rarely        591 Research ~           2
6    32 No        Travel_Freque~      1005 Research ~        2`

Comment: Icould not post it because it was too long, hope the head() only helps